# How can I use an Add-In written for word in excel?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, vsto, add-in, office-addins

I have developed an Add-In for word in C# with Visual Studio and now I want to use that also in excel. How do I go ahead?

Comment: What're you trying to do? Surely your Word Add-In will have Word-type functionality whereas your Excel Add-In will have Excel-type functionality?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Since you are new user, I recommend you read ["How to Ask a Good Question"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Asking question properly will help you get better answers and help others be able to understand your question if they have a similar problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only sensible way to do this is to move all of the common functionality into a separate C# library and reference it from two separate VSTO projects.